# How to capture resizing of QTreeWidget columns

Tags: qt, qtreewidget, qt5.2

I need a column in my QTreeWidget which's width is always x pixels.

So i want to capture a resize of my QTreeWidget columns, to set the with back to my x on resize by user.
But i can't find any Signal like `columnWidthChanged`.

Is there any way to call a function/slot when a columns with is changed?
Or is there any other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of connecting to the `sectionResized` signal and reverting resizes the user made, why not prevent users from resizing the column in the first place, via

```
treeWidget.header().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Fixed)
```

or prevent resizing only individual columns via

```
treeWidget.header().setSectionResizeMode(colIdx, QHeaderView::Fixed)
```

That's easier to implement and much more "natural" to the user.

Comment: Thats a nice solution. Thank you very much @sebastian

Answer (score 1):

The Signal is emitted by the header of the QTreeWidget.
It's `QTreeWidget.header().sectionResized(int column, int oldsize, int newsize)`